# Pass an array object into a NavigationLink which will be edited

Tags: swift, swiftui

I've currently got a NavigationView with a List, using a ForEach loop to show a list of some objects stored in an array, attached to NavigationLink's. When the user clicks on a link for one of the objects, they can edit some of the properties of the object in the link. However, when they try to edit a property, the property either stays the same while typing, or it kicks the user back to the NavigationView. What am I doing wrong?

The child view takes in the object as binding, and the TextFields in the child view also use binding to edit the properties.

I've created a cut down version of everything that shows the problem to make it quicker to read.

**Object Struct**

```
struct Person: Hashable {
    var name: String
    var number: String
}
```

**Navigation View**

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var people: [Person] = testPeople // this contains a few instances of Person
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            NavigationView {
                
                List {
                    ForEach($people, id: \.self) { $person in
                        NavigationLink(destination: PersonView(person: $person)) {
                            Text(person.name)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Navigation Link**

```
struct PersonView: View {
    
    @Binding var person: Person
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(person.name)
            TextField("number", text: $person.number) // this text field allows the user to edit the number property
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Make your struct conform to Identifiable instead of using self in the loop. If you watch Demystifying SwiftUI you will gain a better understanding. SwiftUI is all about identity.

Answer (score 0):

When the number is updated on the `PersonView`, it updates the `Person` in the `ContentView`, which causes the view to be refreshed.

You can get around this by doing a `ForEach` over `people.indices`, as follows:

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        NavigationView {
            
            List {
                ForEach(people.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                    NavigationLink(destination: PersonView(person: $people[index])) {
                        Text(people[index].name)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know why this works, but it does!